# consequences after having logged into a non-tor account

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, login

I know I am not supposed to log into accounts that I ever used before without Tor since then I will give up my anonymity for the website. However, what happens afterwards? If I then visit another website, will it also be able to know it's me or am I anonymous again?

I know that this question has probably been asked here before, but the closest answer I could find was the first one in [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/826/can-i-use-my-personal-account-of-facebook-hotmail-gmail-in-tbb/827#827) question. It states that after having logged into for example facebook, all sites with a facebook-button will be able to recognize me. But what about the one's without a facebook-button?

I am also sorry if this question might seem a little stupid, I am new to Tor and I am still figuring things out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sites without a facebook button would not know who you are. Logging into your real life accounts is bad because it may reveal you to someone who is listening in on the exit node, so the main concert is mainly other adversaries who may be in the middle.